# Custom post type showing index.php

Tags: custom-post-types, template-hierarchy

I am creating a theme and I have created a new Custom Post Type (CPT) called 'Custom Plugins'. I am trying to get this CPT to use its own template. I have created a `single-custom-plugin.php` - it doesn't use that. I have created `single.php` (still early stages with this theme I'm building it to help me learn more) - it doesn't use that either, it uses `index.php` again.

I'm not sure why this isn't working - I have been referring to the WordPress Developer site for help with structuring, in particular [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-post-types) and the below image.

[image: WP Hierarchy]

I would share the code for the pages, but I don't feel it is relevant as both `single.php` and `single-custom-plugin.php` have been temporarily setup as empty files with a single line comment stating the filename. Here is the code for my CPT (again, super basic - maybe I did something wrong here?):

```
function bravo_plugin_posttype() {
    register_post_type('custom-plugins', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Custom Plugins'),
            'singular' => __('Custom Plugin')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'custom-plugins'
        )
    ));
}

add_action('init', 'bravo_plugin_posttype');
```

Comment: First of all... Your CPT is `custom-plugins`, so the template should be `single-custom-plugins.php` (with s at the end). But `single.php` should work just fine. Where do you add these files?

Comment: "it uses index.php again" - what URL are you calling?

Comment: Thanks - it is actually saved as `single-custom-plugins.php`, I edited it as I thought I'd copied it over wrong. I renamed the CPT since testing last and was reloading the page /plugins/{custom-plugin-name} - which explains why it wasn't working. Thanks for the help, all seems to be working as expected now.

Comment: @D.Winning Happy to hear you got it working. Feel free to either self-answer this or delete the question